# including backbone.js in Jasmine's spec

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I am pretty new to backbone.js (and to JavaScript in general) and I am trying to unit test a model with Jasmine (I'm using `jasmine-node` for this). My directory structure is as follows:

```
project/
      src/models/mymodel.js
      spec/mymodel.spec.js
      lib/backbone-min.js
```

Now, my question is how do I make backbone.js available to the model and to the spec without including them in a html page ? I'd like to keep the js code decoupled of the html and just be able to run the tests with jasmine-node

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using the node.js backbone (and underscore) modules you can require them in your model when necessary, something like this.

**/models/car.js**

```
var args = typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? [exports, require('Backbone')] : [window, window.Backbone];

(function (exports, backbone){

    exports.Car = backbone.Model.extend({
        onHornPress: function () {
            return 'HONK';
        }
    });

}).apply(undefined, args);
```

**/specs/car.spec.js**

```
var Backbone = require('Backbone'),
    Car = require('../models/car.js').Car;

describe("when the horn is pressed", function(){
    var car;

    beforeEach(function(){
        car = new Car();
    });

    it("should honk.", function(){
        var result = car.onHornPress();
        expect(result).toEqual('HONK');
    });

});
```

**/myapp.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="models/car.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var car = new Car();

    console.log(car.onHornPress());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```